# jenkins pipeline : when condition and mercurial tags

Tags: jenkins, tags, mercurial

I am trying to run the last step of my jenkins build (deploy) only if the current revision has been tagged with a version number.
I tried to follow the [following example](https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/05/16/pipelines-with-git-tags/) but it is only for GIT.

Here is what I have setup:

1. Jenkins polls my repository and pull the jenkinsfile from it
2. The following jenkinsfile is executed

   ```
   // --- Get sources from mercurial ---
   stage ('Checkout') {
       steps {
           bat "Hg purge --config extensions.purge= --all --print"
           checkout([$class: 'MercurialSCM', credentialsId: '', revision: 'default', source: 'MY_REPO'])
       }
   }

   // --- BUILD ---
   stage ('Build') {
       // my build
   }

   // --- DEPLOY MASTER ---
   stage ('Deploy') {
       when { tag "release*" }
       steps {
           bat "\"${env.WORKSPACE}\\jenkins\\deploy.bat\" \"M:\\dev-FU4\""
       }
   }
   ```

Unfortunately, the deploy part is ignored each time...

Screenshot of the build:

[image: Screenshot of the build]

The problem seems to be the following :

- Mercurial tags are indeed a commit with a line added in the .hgtags file
- When I pull the revision that will be tagged, it is not deployed as there is no tag yet
- When I pull the revision with the "tag commit", it is not beeing deployed, ad the tag refer to an older revision.

Do you have any idea about how to do this ?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the bothering guys, I have figured it out.

I have added :

- A step that determine if the commit is a mercurial tag.
- A step that update to the tag revision, if the tag begins with "release"
- The variable *${hgTagVersion}* is available to use for whichever script will need it.

Here are the sources:

```
// Pipeline stages
stages {

    // --- Get sources from mercurial ---
    stage ('Checkout') {
        steps {
            bat "Hg purge --config extensions.purge= --all --print"
            checkout([$class: 'MercurialSCM', credentialsId: '', revision: 'default', source: 'MY_REPO'])
        }
    }

    stage ('Deployment determination') {
        steps {
            // Determine if Deploy is needed
            script {
                HG_LATEST_DESC = bat (
                    script: '@echo off & hg log --template {desc} --limit 1',
                    returnStdout: true
                ).trim()

                // dummy test of a tag commit
                // HG_LATEST_DESC = "Added tag release-test for changeset 1dcf7a76d27c"

                deployIsNeeded = false
                hgTag = ""
                hgChgSet = ""
                hgTagVersion = ""

                hgsplit = HG_LATEST_DESC.split("Added tag ")
                if (hgsplit.length == 2)
                {
                    hgsplit = hgsplit[1].split(" for changeset ")
                    if(hgsplit.length == 2)
                    {
                        hgTag = hgsplit[0]
                        hgChgSet = hgsplit[1]
                        if(hgTag.contains("release-"))
                        {
                            deployIsNeeded = true;
                            hgTagVersion = hgTag.split("release-")[1]
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (deployIsNeeded)
                {
                    println "Deploy is needed. Hg will checkout to tag and master will be deployed."
                    println "HG tag: ${hgTag}"
                    println "HG changeset: ${hgChgSet}"
                    println "Deploy version: ${hgTagVersion}"
                }
                else
                {
                    println "Deploy is not needed. Build will remain local."
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // --- Checkout to deploy tag ---
    stage ('Deploy tag checkout')
    {
        when { expression { return deployIsNeeded; } }
        steps {
            bat "hg update --clean --rev ${hgChgSet}"
        }
    }

    // --- BUILD ---
    stage ('Build') {
        // my build steps
    }


    // --- DEPLOY MASTER ---
    stage ('Deploy') {
        when { expression { return deployIsNeeded; } }
        steps {
            // my deployment script
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the pipeline viewed from blueocean when there is no need to deploy:
[image]

And when deploy is needed:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Why do you need the "Deploy tag checkout" step?

Comment: And it should be `log --template \'{desc}\'` - the quotes are missing in your code, so the template doesn't work.